# How can I find the line where the code crashes?

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I only got the following error message:

```
[package-2] process has died [pid 14880, exit code -6, cmd /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/package/package_node /package/sub_topic:=/topic __name:=package __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/74b3f964-c270-11ea-9dfa-98e743bf11b3/package-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/74b3f964-c270-11ea-9dfa-98e743bf11b3/package-2*.log
```

How do I find the line of code, where the code crashed?

Edit:
Is there also a way to run the executable via rosrun or roslaunch?

I don't get any errors with `gdb <path to ros executable>`, but the node is also not getting any input topics (for example the navigation goal I usually set in RVIZ).

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356803/how-can-i-find-the-line-where-the-code-crashes?/) by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

you should compile your code to include the debug symbols. You need to run your catkin command with:

```
catkin_make_isolated --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug --pkg <your package>
```

Then you need to run your code with `gdb`.

```
gdb <path to your ros executable>
```

When the code fails use the command `bt` to see the backtrace and see what is going on in your code.

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on 2020-07-12**:
Thanks, I try that.

**Comment by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on 2020-07-12**:
Is there also a way to run the executable via rosrun or roslaunch?

I don't get any errors with `gdb <path to ros executable>`, but the node is also not getting any input topics (for example the navigation goal I usually set in rviz, but I could also publish it via the terminal).

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-07-13**:
That's cool. + 1     I started on ubuntu/linux just to play with ROS. No background in linux and never heard of this(GDB) until your post. Thank you.